# how to combine multiple timestamps and keep the most recent one?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with many timestamps in it, some of which may be null.  Is there a way to combine them all and keep the most recent timestamp so I don't have to reference each timestamp individually?

For example, given this over-simplified example:

```
SELECT blah
FROM foo
WHERE
    ts1 >= '2018-04-17' OR
    ts2 >= '2018-04-17' OR
    ts3 >= '2018-04-17';
```

I suspect there must be a way to turn it into something like this:

```
SELECT blah, somefunc(ts1, ts2, ts3) AS ts
FROM foo
WHERE ts >= '2018-04-17';
```

Comment: Oooh, `COALESCE` gets me most of the way there.  I think I can replace `somefunc` with `COALESCE` in my example, and by ordering the timestamp fields the way I need, it will return the first non-null timestamp.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of postgresql but I think it is nonsense to do so for the same reasons it would be nonsens on an Oracle Db. Hiding the columns behind a function call will it make impossible for the optimizer to use indexes.

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks for your opinion. However, I'd argue that calling `GREATEST(...)`, `LEAST(...)`, or `COALESCE(...)` is obviously not nonsense.  They exist for a reason.  In my case with 8 timestamp fields to compare, it certainly makes the SQL easier to read and maintain since the resulting single timestamp is referenced several times in the WHERE, JOIN, and ORDER BY clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [`greatest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) function:

```
SELECT greatest(now(), 
                now() + interval '1 minute', 
                CURRENT_DATE::timestamptz, 
                NULL);

           greatest            
───────────────────────────────
 2018-04-17 19:40:04.568827+02
```

About NULLs:

> NULL values in the list are ignored. The result will be NULL only if all the expressions evaluate to NULL.

Please note that comparing timestamps (especially timestamps with time zones) to simple date values sometimes result in surprises.  I always try to use something like `date_trunc('day', '2018-01-05'::date)` to get a type that can be compared cleanly.

Comment: Is it normal that such a "virtual" column cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause?  `ERROR: column "ts" does not exist`.  (I may open a new stackexchange ticket.)

Comment: @Stéphane yes, totally expected.  There must be a plethora of questions about it already.

Comment: Yes, thank you again.  Combined your `greatest()` solution with what I found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102373/referring-to-dynamic-columns-in-a-postgres-query